# Connecting a Dockerized MongoDb instance, behing a reverse Nginx proxy on EC2

Tags: mongodb, nginx, docker, amazon-ec2, robo3t

I try to connect Robomongo (or any other MongoDb UI) to a mongo instance, which is dockerized and behind an NGinx reverse-proxy (also dockerized, using jwilder/nginx-proxy) on a EC2 Container-Service instance.

[err screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrRTg.jpg)

I have an application running using this mongo instance, on the same network, working like a charm ; so we know that mongo is running well.

If I try to access directly the container via a browser and targeting the 443 port, i get the following message :

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

I'm using the official mongoDb docker container, which only exposes 27017 ; so my request is redirected from 443 to 27017.

Do you know how can this be achieved ?
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need pass the `--httpinterface` flag to the mongodb container:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --httpinterface
```

This flag are deprecated since version 3.2: HTTP interface for MongoDB

Check [Mongodb Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--httpinterface)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but that didn't do the trick. I forgot to mention the error I'm having in Robomongo, question is updated.